# Fancybox 2.1.3 integration into live site issues

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi to all fancybox lovers. I have created a script that works great locally or live on a server. When i tried to integrate it on an existing webpage where already jQuery v.1.7.1 was used i added below all js and css code in head section, following lines:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.3" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js does all the effect. It also creates a hidden a tag for trigering when a mouse event occurs. This a tag has been created successfully but fancybox could not run its effect. Has this to do with jQuery v.1.7.1 or sth else happens? If it jQuery does matter how could i make this work in different webpages if they use ancient version of jQuery, even if i include v.1.8.2 too? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, two jQuery versions should never be loaded together. Your scripts have no way of knowing which they should use.

You should have a local version of the site to test on, or at the very least a second online one that only you know about (eg on a subdomain).

Try just using the latest jQ - be sure to test everything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer when this script runs alone i use only v1.8.2 not any other of course and there i have no bugs at all.

Comment: How could i make this work in different webpages if they use ancient version of jQuery, even if i include v.1.8.2 too? The solution is to upgrade only their jQuery version? As far as i know from jQuery v.1.6 and later version 2.1.3 of fancybox works ok. So if i leave there only the v1.7.1 of jQuery it will work fine.

Comment: Have one jQuery with a version that works with all scripts. If that is 1.7.1 then fine.